# Best API for syncing Exchange Email/Calendar to my webapp?

Tags: api, email, exchange-server

Looking for additional products similar to www.nylas.com which provide an API to sync my web application with my microsoft exchange email and calendar.

Most email services are aimed at marketing and hosting, whereas I just want a simple connection between exchange and my app, without building an API from the ground up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Exchange EWS?

- [Calendars and EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495623(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [Working with calendar items by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633702(v=exchg.80).aspx)

I do not know your App so a simple cronjob would do it...

*P.S.
By the way I personally think the best way is to access the calendar via the App directly on the device. The reason is that a user normally have ActiveSync configured so that he get all the content on his device. If he change his password he do that on the device. So your app might use a old password and will no longer work. Additional your app try to access content with the old password and might block the user account then. The user got upset and will no longer use it. Accessing the calendar now directly on the device eliminate the need to get the user password and also eleminite the need that the user need to change it in your app...*

Comment: I came across EWS in my research and it does look like the best option! Your input confirms it :)

Comment: By the way I personally think that accessing the content directly on the device might be a better option then accessing it via a API from the server. See more infos above.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Bastian.  But the app itself is on desktop so the connection between the site and their calendar app isn't going to be as clean as it would be on a mobile or tablet device.  From my review it looks like EWS it the best option, however if the calendar sync doesn't work as cleanly as expected I've found an Exchange Library that deals directly with this issue (pyexchange.readthedocs.io). Thanks for you help!